# Sign into different account feature - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Before I part on this adventure to figure out how to setup a section on the users section when signed into admin panel in WordPress which allows the administrator to click the account feature and it will sign them into that users account.  Does anyone know of a quick solution to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin will do what you need:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/